# Having a hard time comparing a hash

Tags: php, cryptography, sha1, hmac, pbkdf2

I am migrating users from one environment to another and we need to verify the user passwords on this new environment. I'm trying to keep users from having to reset their passwords.

My plan is to get the inputted password on login, run it through the same process and see if I get as a result, the existing hash. Then I'll re-hash the password to the other standard.

The problem is, the current hash is being done using pbkdf2 with HMAC-SHA1 algo, 3000 runs.

If I put the information I get from the current site [here](https://asecuritysite.com/encryption/PBKDF2z) I get the correct hash.
If I do the same using `hash_pbkdf2` in PHP I get different results.

```
$hash = hash_pbkdf2('sha1', 'testing123', $salt, 3000, 16); // Found: cb2f9681a3bcad97
$base64 = base64_encode( $hash ); // Found: Y2IyZjk2ODFhM2JjYWQ5Nw==
```

For salt, I tried it in binary, hex, uppercase, lowercase, base64 decoded, encoded. I probably tried every variation.

The values for testing are:

```
Password: testing123
Runs: 3000
Length: 16
Salt: lg4YdsfGNm9zuRizCmk9rA==
Expected result in base64: b11fsnE0JKRaVJTS7uHDqQ==
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What is the current environment? Also PHP, or something else? Can you show how the hash is generated there?

Comment: I don't have `b11fsnE0JKRaVJTS7uHDqQ==` when testing with these values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why but the website you provided and the `hash_pbkdf2()` are not behaving the same :

1. looks like PHP's `hash_pbkdf2()` divides by 2 the key length, so you have to double it to obtain the same hash
2. PHP's `hash_pbkdf2()`'s result corresponds to the `Hex` field on the website

The following code will give you the same base64 value as on the website (according to above comments) :

```
$hash = hash_pbkdf2('sha1',
     /* password */ 'testing123',
         /* salt */ "lg4YdsfGNm9zuRizCmk9rA==",
   /* iterations */ 3000,
/* key length *2 */ 32);
$bin = hex2bin($hash);
$base64 = base64_encode($bin);
```

Comment: I could kiss you right about now.
Although, a minor correction is to base64_decode the salt. otherwise I get another value.

Thank you for pointing out the key length division thing. I was using 16 all this time.